# Why are users getting random resource download lag?

Tags: .net, angular, iis, .net-core, web-developer-toolbar

Our web application is written in Angular 9 having pages that have a combination of Angular as well as .net core views. The users have been reporting slowness, which I was finally able to reproduce on our server. The weird part is, it's completely random what's causing the lag. Sometimes it's a jpg download, sometimes its a javascript file download, other times its an API request.

[image]

This image shows just one page, where one request has a 14.51s execution time. That particular request usually only takes milliseconds to complete. This happens very sporadically and it's always different resources, as mentioned above.

We have App Dynamics installed, and we do not see these requests in app dynamics, which is leading me to believe it's not code related. We do have a lot of API requests happening asynchronously.

We're stumped at this point and looking for any suggestions on what to try. If more information is needed, I can get the answers.  Could this be something server or network related?

Comment: You should firstly use [IIS Log] + [Failed Request Tracing Log] to confirm if the request process shows a slowness. You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis . You should define the failure as 'Time taken (in seconds)' with a proper time limitation (e.g. 10s).

Comment: @XinFang - Finally was able to have our server admins enable this, and it's definitely reporting them. It even happens when we directly request a static file on the server with it's IP Address. The failed request log is created for the slow download.

Comment: @XinFang - After the failed request gets logged, we have no idea what to look at next. It's simply an image file that it happens on. Do you have any recommendations?